# Null en consulta SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta SQL pero no logro generarla correctamente, esto son los parametros que filtro

```
Area = cbbxArea.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxArea.Text;
Linea = cbbxLinea.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxLinea.Text;
Estacion = cbbxEstacion.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxEstacion.Text;
Maquina = cbbxMaquina.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxMaquina.Text;
```

Esta es la consulta SQL

```
"SELECT PC.Lolo, PC.Lo, PC.OpL,  pc.Oph, pc.Hi, PC.Hihi, R.registro, R.fecha,CASE WHEN R.registro >= PC.opL AND R.registro <= PC.opH THEN 'Verde' WHEN ( R.registro < PC.opL OR R.registro > PC.opH) AND ( R.registro >= PC.Lo AND R.registro <= PC.Hi)  THEN 'Amarillo'  ELSE 'Rojo' END AS Registro FROM PuntosControl AS PC JOIN Registro AS R on R.maquina = PC.idMaquina AND R.revision = PC.idPuntoControl AND R.afectacion = PC.idAfectacion WHERE (Null IS Null OR  r.area = Null) AND ('Null' IS Null OR r.linea = 'Null') AND ('Null' IS Null OR r.estacion = 'Null') AND ('Null' IS Null OR r.maquina = 'Null') AND ('Null' IS Null OR r.afectacion = 'Null') AND ('Null' IS Null OR r.revision= 'Null')"
```

la cual funciona con comillas simples mas, al agregar las dobles los parametros null los recibe como 'null' y no los toma en cuenta

```
Object Area, Linea, Estacion, Maquina, Revision, Afectacion;
// ?: conditional operator.  
Area = cbbxArea.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxArea.Text;
Linea = cbbxLinea.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxLinea.Text;
Estacion = cbbxEstacion.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxEstacion.Text;
Maquina = cbbxMaquina.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxMaquina.Text;
Revision = cbbxRevision.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxRevision.Text;
Afectacion = cbbxAfectacion.Text.Equals("Todas") ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : cbbxAfectacion.Text;
MessageBox.Show(Area + " " + Linea + " " + Estacion + " " + Maquina + " " + Revision + " " + Afectacion);
int v = 0, a = 0, r = 0;
int dv = 0, da = 0, dr = 0;
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PC.Lolo, PC.Lo, PC.OpL,  pc.Oph, pc.Hi, PC.Hihi, R.registro, R.fecha,CASE WHEN R.registro >= PC.opL AND R.registro <= PC.opH THEN 'Verde' WHEN ( R.registro < PC.opL OR R.registro > PC.opH) AND ( R.registro >= PC.Lo AND R.registro <= PC.Hi)  THEN 'Amarillo'  ELSE 'Rojo' END AS Registro FROM PuntosControl AS PC JOIN Registro AS R on R.maquina = PC.idMaquina AND R.revision = PC.idPuntoControl AND R.afectacion = PC.idAfectacion WHERE (" + Area + " IS Null OR  r.area = '" + Area + "') AND ("+Linea+" IS Null OR r.linea = '"+Linea+"') AND ("+Estacion+" IS Null OR r.estacion = '"+Estacion+"') AND ("+Maquina+" IS Null OR r.maquina = '"+Maquina+"') AND ("+Revision+" IS Null OR r.afectacion = '"+Revision+"') AND ("+Afectacion+" IS Null OR r.revision= '"+Afectacion+"')", con);
adapt.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

Esto es la ejecución de la consulta y el llenado del dataGrid

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por ultimo la instruccion SQL donde toma los parametros ( '"+Null+"' no lo acepta y se visualiza como 'Null' o '+Null+' los acepta pero cuando no son nulos marca error)

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Por favor incluye un [mcve]. Si no muestras donde generas tu SQL, no podemos ayudar. Pero problemas de comillas son típicos de cuando concatenas valores directamente a la cadena SQL en vez de parametrizar la consulta. Si no lo has hecho ya, eso sería lo primero que corregiría antes de seguir investigando.

Comment: Editado ya con mas información sobre la consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es claramente porque estás tratando de concatenar los valores directamente a tu cadena SQL. La razón más popular por la que se recomienda evitar hacer esto es para protegerse de la inyección SQL. Pero otra razón de peso es para evitar hacerse un lío con las comillas como en tu caso.

La solución es parametrizar la consulta correctamente. Te dejo un modelo simplificado que puedes adaptar a tu consulta:

```
using(var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tabla where (@param1 is null or col1 = @param1) and (@param2 is null or col2 = @param2)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", cbbxParam1.Text == "Todas" ? (object)DBNull.Value : cbbxParam1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cbbxParam2.Text == "Todas" ? (object)DBNull.Value : cbbxParam2.Text);

    adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    // ...
}
```

---

Aparte de parametrizar la consulta, cosa que siempre deberías hacer, personalmente yo haría otra mejora. En vez de siempre efectuar todas esas condiciones en tu SQL, siempre verificando si el valor es null o no, yo armaría la consulta de forma dinámica para minimizar la cantidad de condiciones necesarias y eliminar por completo las condiciones que verifican el NULL.

Requiere un poco más de código, pero el SQL generado es más compacto y eficiente.

Ejemplo:

```
var sql = new StringBuilder("select * from tabla where 1=1");
var parametros = new List<SqlParameter>();

if (cbbxParam1.Text != "Todas")
{
    sql.Append(" and col1 = @param1");
    parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", cbbxParam1.Text));
}

if (cbbxParam2.Text != "Todas")
{
    sql.Append(" and col2 = @param2");
    parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", cbbxParam2.Text));
}

using(var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
    adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Excelentes observaciones y funciona perfecto, aplicare la optimización de la consulta también!
De nuevo gracias por tu tiempo!!